# unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda, Linux Mint 14.1 Nadia

Tags: linux, linux-mint

```
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' Failed.
This is a fatal error
```

Why I got this error message when installing Linux mint 14.1 Nadia 64 bit, even 32 bit, I got this message?

I have 1 partition ext4 with 40 GB. Before I was trying to install it, I was having Window 7 and I formatted it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are the exact commands you performed?

Comment: I am installing it from the GUI

Comment: What GUI? The installer from the Live CD? Synaptic?

Comment: Yes, this is the first time for me to install Linux, and I don't know different ways to install it.

Comment: Some people in the forums suggest trying to boot as a livecd and then starting the installer from the desktop. Perform a clean install. It should work.

Comment: I couldn't understand your suggestion. What do you mean with a clean install?

Comment: Clean install as opposed to upgrade.

Comment: I didn't do upgrade, I made a new installation.

Comment: Do you have other OS installed (e.g. Windows)? Do you have only one HD?